# Overriding required() parameters while using help parameter

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I'm adding options for the Parser in following way:

```
options = new Options()
                .addOption(Option.builder(CONFIG_PARAM)
                        .required()
                        .hasArg(true)
                        .argName(CONFIG_PARAM_NAME + "_path")
                        .desc(CONFIG_PARAM_DESC)
                        .longOpt(CONFIG_PARAM_NAME)
                        .build())
                (...)
                .addOption(Option.builder(HELP_PARAM)
                        .hasArg(false)
                        .longOpt(HELP_PARAM_NAME)
                        .desc(HELP_PARAM_DESC)
                        .build());
```

Now, I would like to allow the user to use only the help command, for ex.

```
mypreciousapp --help
```

With the above solution, it is impossible - I'm receiving the information about missing required parameters

```
Missing required options: c
```

Is there any way to flag the help parameter so it can override the required parameters, and allow its usage alone? I can do this manually, but first I would like to know if there's such option in CLI lib.

Comment: You could try adding an OptionGroup which represents a set of exclusive options (only one option from the group is allowed to be present) and put all your required options in that group (including `-help`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems commons-cli does not support that currently, so I would create a 2nd Options object where the param is not required and parse/check that first, before doing the full parse, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define the options with required arguments as needed
    Options opts = new Options()
            .addOption(Option.builder("p")
                    .required()
                    .hasArg(true)
                    .argName("arg")
                    .desc("description  ")
                    .longOpt("param")
                    .build())
            .addOption(Option.builder("h")
                    .hasArg(false)
                    .longOpt("help")
                    .desc("help description")
                    .build());

    // first check if usage-output was requested
    if (handleHelp(args, opts)) {
        return;
    }

    // now handle the full options
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    final CommandLine cmdLine;
    try {
        cmdLine = parser.parse(opts, args);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Syntax error: " + ex.getMessage());

        printHelp(opts);

        return;
    }

    // now handle options and do your work
}

private boolean handleHelp(String[] args, Options opts) {
    Options helpOpts = new Options()
            .addOption(Option.builder("p")
                    //.required()
                    .hasArg(true)
                    .argName("arg")
                    .desc("description  ")
                    .longOpt("param")
                    .build())
            .addOption(Option.builder("h")
                    .hasArg(false)
                    .longOpt("help")
                    .desc("help description")
                    .build());

    CommandLineParser helpParser = new DefaultParser();
    final CommandLine cmdLine;
    try {
        cmdLine = helpParser.parse(helpOpts, args);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Syntax error: " + ex.getMessage());

        printHelp(opts);

        return true;
    }

    if(cmdLine.hasOption("h")) {
        printHelp(opts);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private void printHelp(Options opts) {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out)) {
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();

        formatter.printHelp(pw, 80, "myapp", "test-header", opts,
                formatter.getLeftPadding(), formatter.getDescPadding(), "test-footer", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution can be the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // define the options with required arguments as needed
    Options opts = new Options()
            .addOption(Option.builder("p")
                    .required()
                    .hasArg(true)
                    .argName("arg")
                    .desc("description  ")
                    .longOpt("param")
                    .build())
            .addOption(Option.builder("h")
                    .hasArg(false)
                    .longOpt("help")
                    .desc("help description")
                    .build());

    // first check if usage-output was requested
    if (Arrays.asList(args).contains("--help")) {
        HelpFormatter help = new HelpFormatter();
        help.printHelp("betgenius-stream", opts);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cli = parser.parse(options, args);
    // now handle options and do your work
}
```

In this way it is not necessary to rewrite the options.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fluent wrapper for the commons-cli library: https://github.com/bogdanovmn/java-cmdline-app

The -h option is already built-in. You don't need to manage it in your own code.